# Suppressing warning “Statement may not be safe to log in statement format” in mysqld.log

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I've noticed the mysqld.log is being filled up with these log messages about the statement not be safe to log in a statement format for the MySQL replication.

I know the query is fine, and from what I've googled the query is fine, but there is a bug in MySQL that it reports the query as potentially being unsafe when it is fine (I know what this error is referring to and why some queries may not be potentially safe to run as a statement replication).

What I want to know is there a way to stop these messages from being written to the log file, as the log file is huge (over 40GB) and growing, but don't want to change the replication from statement to binary logging.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at adjusting log_warnings=0 but make sure to read the manual on implications when you change this variable

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings